# Queries on distribution of prime divisors by magnitude?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, square-free

[Erdos-Kac law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) state a typical number of magnitude $n$ has $\log\log n$ prime factors and we know probability of square free integers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

> 1. What is the probability distribution of square free $(a,b)$ balanced integers $n$ where if $p|n$ and $q|n$ we have $ap<q<bp$? What balancing parameters gets to $\frac1{O(\log n)}$ probability?

I would think a typical square free odd number is $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ balanced for a constant $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ with probability close to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

> 2. What is the probability distribution of square free $(a,b)$ balanced integers $n$ where we know there is an integer $r|n$ with magnitude $n^{0.25\pm\epsilon'}$ where $\epsilon'\in(0,0.25)$?

Comment: Can this really be what you mean? If $n$ is even, for example, then all prime factors of $n$ have to be less than $2b$, and such integers will be extremely rare.

Comment: 'probability distribution of square free $(a,b)$ balanced integers $n$ where if $p|n$ and $q|n$ we have $ap<q<bp$'. So I guess the distribution would have to rule out even numbers.

Comment: Suppose the answers to 1. were "It approaches zero for fixed a and b" and "There aren't any". What would your reaction be?

Comment: a and b can be functions of n or else we won't get 1/log n probability. I would also think my guess was not precise.

Comment: First, you don't really need two parameters, since by symmetry between $p$ and $q$ you might as well take $a=1/b$. The density of integers $n$ all of whose prime factors are less than about $\exp(\log n \log\log\log n / \log\log n)$ is about $O(1/\log n)$; so that's what you'd have to choose $b$ to be, I believe, since most integers have a small prime factor.

Comment: So the parameters are subexponential. Ok.